# How to create channel updating proposal and how to sign it

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

In Hyper Ledger Fabric, channel update needs some sign, but how to create channel update proposal, and how to sign it.

Is there any command to do that? Or, do we have to collect sign manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is documentation available [in the Fabric readthedocs](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/config_update.html) for doing configuration updates.

You may use the tool `configtxlator` in conjunction with your favorite editors/tools to modify the configuration documents as JSON, and you may use `peer channel signconfigtx` to add signatures if more than one signature is required, and `peer channel update` to add a signature and submit.

The `peer channel signconfigtx` command modifies the transaction in place to add signatures, so each member needs to run this command serially.  If parallel collection and dissemination is desired, you may use `configtxlator` or the protobufs directly, to share the update, collect the signatures, and assemble them yourself.